# Inheritance of text-align in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-cascade

I want to set all the 'p' tags to 'justify' and just the header section to 'center'.
One more thing to note here is that I selected paragraphs with type selector (specificity: 1) and the header with id selector (specificity: 100).

Moreover #header selection comes after p selection. If it is true that text-align property is inheritable, I guess 'center' style is supposed to get higher importance over 'justify' for the 'p' tag in header. But it isn't working that way.

I even checked out similar questions on stackoverflow and used text-align: initial over #header p. That didn't work either.

```css
p {
  text-align: justify;
}

#header {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1>Article Name</h1>
  <p>Author Name</p>
</div>
<p>
  ... more paragraphs
</p>
```

Comment: Here I wanted to set all the 'p' tags to 'justify' and just the header section to 'center'.  — And you have. I don't understand how the result of running the live demo in the question differs from what you expect.

Comment: Properties are only inherited if they are unset on the element. Since you are setting `text-align` on `p`, the property will not be inherited from `#header`.

Comment: You won't usually notice justified text until you have more than one full line's worth

Comment: @Quentin I think OP is expecting `Author Name` to be centred.

Answer (score 1):

```css
#header, #header >p {
  text-align: center !important;
}

p {
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1>Article Name</h1>
  <p>Author Name</p>
</div>
<p>
  ... more paragraphs
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create classes that you can reuse :

```
.justify{
    text-align: justify;
}

.center{
    text-align: center;
}

<div class="center">
  <h1>Article Name</h1>
  <p class="center">Author Name</p>
</div>
<p class="justify">
  ... more paragraphs
</p>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work.

Comment: Hello. Thank you !